# Return Account ID Second Object

Tags: salesforce-id, apex

I'm still very new to Apex.

What is the best way to return Account ID to my Object2__c?  I have two Objects, Object2__c and Account object. These objects have a 1:1 relationship.  What I'm trying to do is update or insert into Account object based on an external ID.  Using Upsert would be the best but it doesn't solve 100% of the issues.

Long story short, my users also create accounts in the Account object before the external ID is created. by created leads into Accounts.  I have to do a check on the Account object for the first matching Account Name  and return the Account ID to Object2__c.  Object2__c is just a stagging object

How would I go about doing this? I've been playing around with the codes below but I'm not getting anywhere fast.

```
list<account> myAccounts = new list<account>();
myAccounts = [Select ID, Name from Account limit 10];

Map<String, Account> businessMap = new Map<String, Account>();

for ( Account a : myAccounts ){
businessMap.put(a.ID, a.Name);
}

for ( ID aID : businessMap.keySet() ){
system.debug(businessMap.get(aID));
}
```

Comment: in what context is this code running - a trigger? and what kind of trigger (before/after insert/update) ?

Answer (score 2):

So if I understand you correctly, you:

1. On Insert of an account, find any accounts:

   - With the same name
   - Where the External ID Field is blank
2. For any that are found, create a new object2__c record

if correct you can start with a trigger on account after insert:

```
for trigger CreateStageObject on Account(After Insert){

      Account[] stageAccounts;

      Set<String> acctNames = New Set<String>();

      //Get Account Names
      for(Account a : trigger.new){
           acctNames.add(a.name);
      }

      //Cycle through accounts meeting criteria using indexed fields
     //NOTE - you may have to remove the NOT ID IN part and add it in the loop. I am not sure if that makes it non-selective or not and I cannot seem to find the query optimizer anymore..
     for(Account a : [Select ID, Name From Account Where Name IN :acctNames AND (NOT ID IN :trigger.new)]){
         if(string.isBlank(a.EXTERNALIDFIELD))
              stageAccounts.add(a);
     }

     //Now build stage objects
     Object2__c[] objTBI = New Object2__c[]{};
     for(Account a : stageAccounts) 
          objTBI.add(New Object2__c(Name='Your Name', ACCOUNTFIELD = a.id);


     database.insert(objTBI,false);

}
```

Comment: Hi Eric, thank you for replying. This will not be based on insert.  I'll have a scheduled job that execute this class at a specified time.

Comment: So, once you find the matching Account name without External ID, it should retrieve the Account ID and update the record in the Object2__c.  The field name will be   "Acct_ID__c".

Comment: @user7123 - If you update it accordingly yet. And you can convert it to a class and pass in the records instead of the trigger.new stuff

Comment: HI Eric,  Can you help to troubleshoot what I have below.  The error is in the last For loop.

Comment: @user7123 - Troubleshoot what?

Comment: Sorry, I'm not sure how I should post the code for you to review.

Comment: @user7123 - Start a new question

Comment: Hi Eric,  here is the link to my other post.  http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/q/60567/7123