# Need Help Debug this code

Tags: apex

The problem is in the last For loop.  Please nelp to debug.  Thanks

```
List<Business__c> businesses = new List<Business__c>();
Set<string> combineIds = new Set<string>();

for(Business__c bus : [Select Combine__c from Business__c]) {
    combineIds.add(bus.Combine__c);
}

List<Account> accounts = [SELECT ID, Combine__c, Market__c, Name FROM Account WHERE Combine__c IN :combineIds];

Business__c busRec = New Business__c();

For(Account a: accounts){
    busRec.add(New Business__c(Name = a.Name, a.Combine__c, busRec.acctId = a.ID, busRec.Market = a.Market__c));

    database.Upsert(busRec,false);
 }
```

Comment: What exactly is the problems? What error are you getting

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Taking a stab at the issues

take the update outside of the loop and make the busRec a list:

```
Business__c[] busRec = New Business__c[]{};

    For(Account a: accounts){
        busRec.add(New Business__c(Name = a.Name, a.Combine__c, busRec.acctId = a.ID, busRec.Market = a.Market__c));


     }

      database.Upsert(busRec,false);
```

Comment: @user7123 - Can you please mark as accepted answer then so this question does not keep getting bumped

Comment: Sorry, you resolved so quick yesterday it won't let me accept it.  It is now accepted.  Thank you so much.

Comment: what if I wanted to do an update at the end instead of Upsert.  Where would I get the ID on Business Object for the update function?

Comment: Ok, may be I can not update with External ID. External ID can only be use with Upsert.